# react native for web: expo-camera failed to scan qrcode

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code, expo-camera

I am developing a web app with react native for web, and I want to scan qrcode but it does not work, without errors.

I put the codes on snack, ran it on mobile with Expo Go, it worked perfectly. However, when I published it on github web, and open it with mobile browser (iOS Safari), the camera worked normally, but no qrcode was read (just no reponse when I put a qrcode inside).

Code info:
I referred sample code on [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#usage) and [expo-barcode-scanner](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/#usage). Since expo-barcode-scanner does not support web, I imported expo-camera only.

Version info:

- "expo": "~42.0.1"
- "expo-camera": "~11.2.2"
- "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4"
- "react": "16.13.1"
- "react-dom": "16.13.1"
- "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz"
- "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"

Also, I checked [this issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12926), and tried the followings:

1. open /node_modules/expo-camera/package.json, set "@koale/useworker" to "4.0.1"
2. run `npm i` under root dir
3. open /node_modules/expo-camera/node_modules/@koale/useworker/package.json, confirmed that the version is 4.0.1

But it still did not work.

I feel confused now, did I take wrong solutions? Is there any workarounds?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scanning QR code, the `barCodeScannerSetting` is required. Like this:

```
barCodeScannerSettings={{ barCodeTypes: [BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr], }}
```